# How to design a history for n:m relations

Tags: sql, plsql, many-to-many

**Problem:**

I have a n:m relation between a table `A` and another table `B` and it is required to have the complete history of this relation, in other words I must be able to reproduce the status of any point the past.

**Ideas:**

My first attempt is to dissect to relation into an 1:m and an m:n relation by inserting a dummy table to save the status of the relation at any given time when some changes occur. Like this:

```
TABLE A         TABLE B
--------        ---------
ID   INT        ID    INT                   

TABLE HIST             TABLE CROSS_REF
----------             -----------------
ID        INT          REF_B_ID      INT
REF_A_ID  INT          REF_HIST_ID   INT
VERSION   TIMESTAMP
```

*Pro:* It is easy to query the required information. *Con:* This attempt will create a lot of redundant data, especially when the "B"-Side is large and there are only minor changes. (like for example in the use-case "Company -- Employee")

A second approach would be to maintain two n:m relationships, one for the current status and one for the changes that occured.

```
TABLE A         TABLE B
--------        ---------
ID   INT        ID    INT                   

TABLE CHANGES          TABLE CROSS_REF
----------             -----------------
REF_A_ID     INT          REF_A_ID      INT
REF_B_ID     INT          REF_B_ID   INT
ACTION_TIME  TIMESTAMP
ACTION_TYPE  VARCHAR
```

*Pro:* No redundant data. *Con:* It is difficult to query the status for a specific point of time in the past.

**Questions**

- Do you have another suggestion how I could design the data model for this application?
- If there is no really better way to solve this: Which way should I go? Or does it mainly depend on the given use case, like the example described above?
- If I go for the second approach, how could a query for the status at a specfic point of time in the past look like? I am able to solve this problem on the client side, but I'd like to know a solution on the database side as well. (PL/SQL would be feasible as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this commonly used model?

```
create table cross_ref
  ( a_id    references a
  , b_id    references b
  , from_ts timestamp
  , to_ts   timestamp
  , primary key (a_id, b_id, from_ts)
  );
```

(NB I used `timestamp` as you did; normally I would use `date`)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, indeed this is a nice idea. In the very end I want to use JPA for ORM, so it might be a little bit tricky to use this approach, but nevertheless it is a good starting point for further consideration

Comment: Tony, I have the same problem as the OP. If I understood your answer, you're recommending a separate table to hold the relationship at a point in time. I don't understand the from and to? Do you use them to track the validity of the record? Also, I need to store the history of my whole record, not only the relationships, I've read in several places I should use the approach of creating a history table that stores only the updated column. Adding your solution to that, would I need 2 separate tables or could I use the same one and just add the extra fields? Is there a better solution for my case

Comment: @eestein, the purpose of the `from_ts` and `to_ts` columns is to "be able to reproduce the status of any point the past" as per OP's requirement. So you could query `select b_id from cross_ref where a_id = 1 and date '2015-01-01' between from_ts and to_ts` to find out the Bs associated with an A at that date.

Comment: @TonyAndrews Ok, I currently do not need that... would you say merging your solution with the one I've mentioned is the best option in my case? I'd have a table with `tb1_id`, `tb2_id`, `column_name` and columns for the new and old values. What are your thoughts? Thanks for your time :)

Comment: As for storing "history", it depends on what your requirements are.  For a security audit trail ("user Joe changed the salary of employee 123 to 20000 at 11:23 on 29/07/2015") you might use a generic table with rows like (table_name, column_name, key, old_value, new_value, user, datetime).  But if it is to answer business questions then a history record with all the columns of the original plus from/to dates might be better.  Sometimes this gets combined i.e. the current record is also in the "history" (only) table with from=when valid and to=null

Comment: Ok, I got that, I read about "security audit trail" here on SO but right now I'm looking for a revision/version history. The user should be able to restore the record to a specific past version. I started creating a different table with all columns from my main table plus some extra columns as you mentioned, but then I read that wasn't the best approach because a lot of fields wouldn't be used and take a lot of space... but my main concern is how to save that whole record WITH the relationship data. I'm looking at saving them using XML, that's my current solution, if you have any ideas :/